# Panels in GNOME keep resetting or turning blank

Tags: gnome-panel

I keep having problems with my GNOME panels. What I have done is moved both panels to the bottom of the screen and added a bunch of icons / widgets etc.

However I am finding often that when I login sometimes my panels have been restored to the default state with the icon panel at the top but with nothing other than the Firefox icon.
Also sometimes the panels are in the correct place but all the icons have been removed from at least one of the panels.

This is quite irritating as I seem to have to spend time setting my entire panel up again at least once every 2 days or so.
Also my wine applications (such as Spotify) used to be able to dock in the main notification area, now they are docked in a separate "wine dock" which hovers on the desktop, this is not really ideal as I prefer to keeps these in one place.

In my `$HOME/.gnome2/panel2.d/default/launchers` folder there seems to be a bunch of symlinks which appear to be the icons that I would usually have on my panel, but they are not visible on the panel.

Other than this all my profile settings and application settings do not seem to have been lost or changed, just the panels.

I can't seem to find much evidence of anyone else having this problem and I've never had it before so I am confused as to why this has started happening and what I can do to prevent it.

Answer (score 1):

alt+f2 type : gconf-editor

apps--->
panel-->
global->

Then Check "locked_down"

It should prevent the panels from further change

but you must uncheck it to change things on the panels

Answer (score 0):

You could also use this handy utility to save and restore your settings via a handy script with a simple GUI, or restore the default Ubuntu panels.

http://www.starryhope.com/linux/ubuntu/2010/restore-the-default-panels-in-ubuntu/